# One definite integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be a continuous function, and $\int_0^1 f(1-x^2) dx=\sqrt{3}$. Find $\int_0^2xf(2x-x^2)dx$.

I tried this:
Let $x=t+1$, then
$$\int_0^2xf(2x-x^2)dx = \int_{-1}^1 (t+1)f(1-t^2) dt$$.
Also, $\int_{-1}^1f(1-x^2) dx = 2\int_{0}^1f(1-x^2) dx $.

But I don't know what to do next. Both substituting and integrating by parts does not seem to work...

Comment: Is the answer $2\sqrt 3$ ?

Comment: @Sam Yes, see the answer following.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\int_{-1}^1 (t+1)f(1-t^2) dt=\underbrace{\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{\int_{-1}^1 tf(1-t^2) dt}}_\text{integrand is an odd function}+\int_{-1}^1 f(1-t^2) dt=2\sqrt3$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-1}^1 tf(1-t^2)dt+2\int_0^1f(1-t^2)dt=0+2\sqrt 3$ . [Let $g(t)=tf(1-t^2)$. Then $g(-t)=-g(t)$].